# Cordova on iOS: Attempt to present on a controller while a presentation is in progress

Tags: ios, cordova

I'm having an issue where I select an image in a Cordova app and then when the image is successfully selected my plugin is supposed to launch a photo editor.

Here is the code for the show method in my plugin:

```
- (void) show:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*) command
{
    NSString* arg0 = [command.arguments objectAtIndex:0];

    NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:arg0];
    NSString* imagePath = [url path];
    UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];

    self.aviary = [[AFPhotoEditorController alloc] initWithImage:image];
    [self.aviary setDelegate:self];
    [self.viewController presentModalViewController:self.aviary animated:YES];
}
```

The photo editor doesn't display and the following warning comes up:

Attempt to present AFSDKViewController: 0x9e73470 on MainViewController: 0x9fc9780 while a presentation is in progress!

So if I add a delay to my call to the plugin like the following the photo editor launches fine but I would prefer not to have to include a delay in my code just for iOS.  What is the proper way to avoid this race condition?

```
setTimeout(function() {
    // code that calls my photo editor plugin
}, 1000);
```